# Bound class not resolving in package

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-service-container

I have an API class that is being bound into the container via a service provider:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('apiclient', fn($app) => new APIClient($app));
}
```

It is not defined as a package in `'app/config/app.php'` as it is in packages.json.

It is constructed with `$app` as there is a parameter in the URL that is used to switch the base_uri the API uses for its requests - similar to how the Spatie Multi-tenancy application uses a parameter in the URL to switch between landload databases.

This all works throughout the application as anticipated like this:

```
$user = APIClient::get()
->class('users')
->routing('/123123/123123/123123')
->getResult();
```

I don't believe the inner workings of the API class to be important, as, essentially, the methods are used to build the full URI and / or any POST data required - if I am wrong, let me know and I will update.

Anyway, the issue at hand.
I am looking to use the API to authenticate users with two new user providers that I have added to `app/congif/auth.php` like this

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'sl_business',
        ],
]
///
'providers' => [
        'sl_business' => [
            'driver' => 'sl_business'
        ]
]
```

Where `'sl_business'` is registered as an auth provider:

```
Auth::provider('sl_business', function ($app, array $config) {
    // Return an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider...
    return new EmployeeUserProvider($this->app['hash'], $config['model']);
});
```

The LoginRequest is correctly using this user provider, however, the EmployeeUserProvider is unable to use the `APIClient` class.  The following, which works fine in the 'application', is not resolving the class in the package:

```
$user = APIClient::get()
        ->class('employee')
        ->endPoint('login')
        ->route('/'.$loginid.'/'.$password.'/')
        ->getResult();
```

When I debug with `dd(resolve(APIClient::class));`, I get:

```
Target class [Business\API\Auth\Providers\AIPClient] does not exist.
```

`Business\API\Auth\Providers` is the namespace of the provider I am working in, and no, the AIPClient does not exist in that directory, it exists in `Business\API`.

All these files are in the same package, so I guess I am trying to determine the best way to resolve a class from the application within my package, or, if that is even possible.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the class construct method to accept the APIClient as an argument and, change the provider registration to include said client:

```
Auth::provider('sl_business', function ($app, array $config) {
    // Return an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider...
    return new EmployeeUserProvider($this->app['hash'], $config['model'], new APIClient($this->app));
});
```

And the constructor:

```
public function __construct(HasherContract $hasher, $model, APIClient $api)
{
    $this->model = $model;
    $this->hasher = $hasher;
    $this->api = $api;
}
```

I can now access the APIClient throughout the user provider as `$this->api`